# Как получить индекс строки в WinForms, DevExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Как получить индекс или значения выбранной строки в gridControl от DevExpress в WinForms? В стандартном datagridview делаю так =

```
gridOrder.SelectedRows[i].Cells["order_number"].Value
```

Хочу заменить стандартный datagridview на gridControl, но встречаю много отличий, думал они будут идентичный просто gridControl более функционален, а получается они почти разные? Может есть документация на русском у кого-то для него?

Comment: на русском документацию не встречал, и по мне так с WinForms на WPF перейти проще чем подстроиться под "особенности" DevExpress, но это только личные эмоции. Если DevExpress устанавливали полностью, то в папке куда устанавливали, должна быть папочка с семплами, там основные приемы работы с их контролами показаны, а если нужна экзотика - попробуйте стукнуться в техподдержку.

Comment: @rdorn в WPF та же проблема

Comment: в WPF - MVVM, там не нужно знать индексы строк в контролах если VM реализована правильно. Но это уже спор не по делу.

Comment: @rdorn - В WinForms тоже можно использовать MVVM.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так я ж не отрицаю что в формах тоже так можно, просто в WPF это намного легче сделать. только это тоже не поможет решить проблему, я не так давно тоже долго бодался с DevExpress, но уже не помню как решилось в итоге. Там в роде в аргументах события какие-то полезные свойства были.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Александр, я не давно использую c#, часто вижу вы советуете MVVM, Вы как программист только его используете, Вам хватает?

Comment: Не-не-не! Я мало работал с WPF, а именно там MVVM считается стандартом. Поэтому я не могу советовать то, что сам плохо знаю. Я сторонник подходов [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(принцип)), [YAGNI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI), [DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don’t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 3):

Используйте метод [ColumnView.GetSelectedRows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic) для получения *индексов* выделенных строк:

```
int[] rowHandles = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
```

Если множественное выделение отключено(по умолчанию или с помощью опции режима выделения [ColumnView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsSelection_MultiSelecttopic)) используйте свойство [ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic):

```
int rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
```

Получить же сами значения ячеек или объект строки целиком можно с помощью
методов [ColumnView.GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowCellValuetopic)/[ColumnView.GetRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic.aspx):

```
int number = (int)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "order_number");
//...
Order order = (Order)gridView1.GetRow(rowHandle);
```

Для сфокусированной строки есть "сокращенные" методы [GetFocusedRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetFocusedRowtopic)/[GetFocusedRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetFocusedRowCellValuetopic(vb2Cmw))

p.s. Полезные ссылки:

- [Focus and Selection Handling](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114764)
- [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753/obtain)

p.p.s. Как верно заметили в комментариях, MVVM можно использовать и в WinForms, и как раз DevExpress является единственным вендором, предоставляющим поддержку [MVVM на уровне WinForms контролов](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument113955) из коробки.

Для случая с выделенной строкой код биндинга может выглядеть [вот так](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114098):

```
// привязка вьюмодели списка заказов к гриду
var fluent = mvvmContext1.OfType<OrderCollectionViewModel>();
// привязка индикатора загрузки(если во вьюмодели есть асинхронка)
fluent.SetBinding(gridView1, gView => gView.LoadingPanelVisible, x => x.IsLoading); 
fluent.SetBinding(gridControl1, gControl => gControl.DataSource, x => x.Entities);
// привязка выделенной строки
fluent.WithEvent<ColumnView, FocusedRowObjectChangedEventArgs>(gridView1, "FocusedRowObjectChanged")
    .SetBinding(x => x.SelectedEntity,
        args => args.Row as Order,
            (gView, entity) => gView.FocusedRowHandle = gView.FindRow(entity));
```